# Can't Check Checkbox in jQuery Collapsable Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm using the following code to allow for an accordion effect on a series of table rows.

```
        $('.accordian-body').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(this).closest("table")
                .find(".collapse.in")
                .not(this)
                .collapse('toggle')
        });
```

Inside the collapsed rows I also have a series of checkboxes, to allow for options to be selected:

```
        <div style="float:right;margin-top:-5px;" class="checkbox check-primary checkbox-circle">
           <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1">
           <label for="checkbox1"></label>
         </div>
```

These checkboxes cannot be checked or unchecked, even if not disabled, although the mouse pointer will chance to indicate a clickable element is there.

How can I re-enable the checkboxes?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us a jsfiddle example code?

Comment: A jsFiddle link is more appreciated.

Comment: Weirdly I can't get it to replicate in a jsfiddle - I'll see if I can isolate the issue further.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4gj01o2m/

Comment: The problem seems to be the label elements - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4gj01o2m/1/ - which are overlapping the checkboxes